# where should I store words for hangman game

Tags: javascript

I want to make a hangman game and I need to access the words with javascript.  But where should I store these words?  Is it directly with a `const` or something else?  Can you help me please?

Comment: [An array, perhaps?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: In a huge file, line by line. read a random line out of it, so you wont have all the words in memory

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with this?

```js
const words = ['word', 'words', 'wordy', 'worldly', ...]
```

If you show us the format your list of words is in we could provide a more specific solution.

Comment: Won't it cause performance loss?  For example, if I have 500 words, is this method suitable?

Comment: 500 words is chump change for any computer you're likely to be using. I'd only worry about optimizing beyond this simple solution once you hit millions of words. Keep in mind 1 million 8 character (english ascii) words is only 8MB (+some overhead) your computer likely has nearly 1000x that much memory.

Comment: sorry, wrong wordlist https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-1273.html